# Auto-trigger for thresholds with time series data

Tags: time-series, clickhouse

I wonder if the Clickhouse is a possible solution for the next task.

- I'm collecting time-series data (for example pulse measurements of people)
- I have different types of thresholds (for example min and max pulse value based on the age)
- Once a pulse for an individual human reached the appropriate threshold, I want to trigger external service

In other words, what I looking for beyond a regular time-series storage is:

- ability to set multiple thresholds
- detect if the value is beyond the threshold automatically
- emit some kind of event to 3rd party

Any other tools suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CH does not have such features.

Comment: just suggestion: how about using specialized time-series databases (for example, *Prometheus*) and webhooks on alerts - look for example [Prometheus AlertManager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#webhook_config).

Comment: @vladimir thanks for the suggestion. for now, what I'm to find in existing solutions is an option to send an alert only once when the threshold triggered (until it will be re-triggered next time). E.g. if value became more than X, I got an alert. But I have to get an alert again, only if value becomes lower than X and more than X again. This is what seems impossible with Clickhouse. Seems Prometheus can help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clickhouse have partial features for this task

you can try to write your own code (python, golang everything else) as an external process 
which can use `LIVE VIEWS` and `WATCH` for trigger event detection, look article which describes these features
https://www.altinity.com/blog/2019/11/13/making-data-come-to-life-with-clickhouse-live-view-tables

and this code should emit an event to 3rd party system

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Looks like the possible solution.